# Powershell: Script not running from command line but runs from ISE?

Tags: powershell

Here is the function I call in my script:

```
Function SetUp-ScheduledTasks
{
param
(
    [string]$Server = "",
    [string]$TaskName = "",
    [string]$ReleasePath = "",
    [string]$User = "",
    [string]$Pwd = ""   
)

try
{
    Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

    Remove-ScheduledTask -ComputerName $Server -TaskName $TaskName Get-ScheduledTask
    Create-ScheduledTask -ComputerName $Server -TaskName $TaskName -TaskRun $ReleasePath  -Schedule "DAILY" -StartTime "02:00:00" -RunAsUser $User -RunAsPwd $Pwd

    exit 1
}   
catch
{           
    exit 0
}

}
```

When I call this from within the Powershell_ISE in the script file but outside any function, it works perfectly, here's what I do for that: `SetUp-ScheduledTasks "myserver" "MyTask1" "c:\release" "theuser" "thepassword"`

However when I call it from PS command line like this:
`. .\ScheduledTasks.ps1 SetUp-ScheduledTasks "myserver" "MyTask1" "c:\release" "theuser" "thepassword"` It does not do anything.

I also tried qualifying each parameter with a dash and name, but that still didn't work.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: When you run from the ISE are you running at the command prompt or from within the editor window at the top?

Comment: From ISE I just click on the green run button, in the editor window.

Comment: So then you are doing  two different things.  You are adding it to the script, then trying to run it as a parameter from a command line which is totally different.

Comment: No, I'm running from within the script just as test to see if the functions work. But I actually comment that call out because i really want to run it from the command line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me repeat what you are doing, but with a simpler example:

You have a function, like so:

```
function a{
write-host "this is function a"
}
```

Let's say you save it in `test.ps1`

Now, to test this in ISE, you do below in test.ps1:

```
function a{
write-host "this is function a"
}

a
```

And press the Run button and you get the expected output, in this case `this is function a`

Now, you use the original test.ps1 without the bottom line  (a) and, call it like so from console:

`. .\test.ps1 a`

And it doesn't give the output. Why? `a`, the intended function call is being passed as parameter to the script and the function a doesn't get called.

You have to do like this:

`. .\test.ps1; a`

PS: Aren't you using `exit 0` and `exit 1` in wrong places?

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thank you. As for the exit codes, I'm under the impression that to signify success, you exit with a 1 inside the try block and with a 0 in the catch. Is that incorrect? Should they be elsewhere? Thanks again!!

Comment: Oh so it's just a preference thing? Or it has to be like that?